# Getting empty list of array values from Json Data?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating multi-select values and getting a list of array values.I want to show the list based on array named **type**. And  Getting empty values.

If the array **type** value is **Test** then display the values in Table.

[image]
Here i am getting the json data in console log:

```
    [{"id":"12345","name":"Test1","lastname":"angular","type":["Test"]}

{"id":"2222","name":"Test2","lastname":"angular123","type":["Test12345"]}

{"id":"3333","name":"Test3","lastname":"testname","type":["Test", "Test12345"]}]
```

**Typescript class:**

```
     this.getservice.getall().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
     this.values = data;
      this.type1 = this.values.filter(val => val.type === ['Test']);
      console.log('submit Post click happend' + JSON.stringify(this.type1));
      this.type2 = this.values.filter(val => val.type === ['Test12345']);
      console.log('submit Post click happend' + JSON.stringify(this.type2));
```

**Html**

```
 // display the type1 list values
<tbody *ngFor="let pro of type1">
          <tr>
            <td style="text-align: start;">
                    {{ pro.name }}
            </td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
```

Comment: do you want filter as `this.type1 = this.values.filter(val => val.type.indexOf('Test')>=0);`? Take account that an array is only equal to itself, not when has the same values that anohter one. This is the reason you has no values. tip: you can compare strings, so, you can use `val.type.join(',')=='Test'"` if you want the exact values

Answer (score 0):

Try this one I hope this will work as you expected..!!!

```js
 const type2=[{id:"2222",name:"Test2",lastname:"angular123",type:["Test", "Test12345"]}]
 
const filter = 'Test';
const filteredResult = type2.filter((item) => {
        return (item.type.indexOf(filter) >= 0);
 });
console.log(filteredResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your Typescript code, you assign the filter results on separate variables and hence you definitely need to use them in your HTML.

The way you have it have can lead to async issues. Your templating tries to render something that is not yet ready. I mean the variable `type1`.

You can use the `async` pipe, which subscribes and unsubscribed automatically.

In order to do this, you have to prepare your data accordingly

If your data are

```
[
  {"id":"12345","name":"Test1","lastname":"angular","type":["Test"]},
  {"id":"2222","name":"Test2","lastname":"angular123","type":["Test12345"]},
  {"id":"2222","name":"Test2","lastname":"angular123","type":["Test", "Test12345"]}
]
```

and assuming that you have a type like this

```
interface YourType {
  id: number
  name: string
  lastname: string
  type: string[]
}
```

you can then create a method which filters the data

```
getByType(typeName: string): Observable<YourType[]>() {
  return this.getservice.getall().pipe(
    map(data => data.filter((val) => val.type.includes(typeName) )
  )  
}
```

*If you notice, I do not subscribe the observables*

Then in your templating, you can use this method along with the **async** pipe

```
<tbody *ngFor="let pro of getByType('Test') | async">
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: start;">
              {{ pro.name }}
      </td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Side info, having a method in the templating is not correct as it runs multiple times (on each change detection). Ideally, you could create separate variables and use those instead.

Like

```
this.typeTest$ = getByType('Test')
```

I added the dollar sign at the end of the variable which denotes that this is an observable and should be used along with the **async** pipe